How to configure Neovim for C# .NET development with VS Code/Visual Studio-compatible formatting?
I primarily use Visual Studio Professional 2019 and VS Code for C# .NET Framework and WPF XAML development. I want to try Neovim, particularly for its undotree feature, but I need to ensure consistent code formatting across all my editors.
Current Setup
In VS Code, my formatting configuration looks like this (settings.json):
{
  "editor.formatOnSave": true,
  "editor.defaultFormatter": "esbenp.prettier-vscode",
  "[csharp]": {
    "editor.defaultFormatter": "ms-dotnettools.csharp"
  },
  "[xml]": {
    "editor.defaultFormatter": "DotJoshJohnson.xml"
  }
}

In Visual Studio, I use the default C# formatter (Ctrl+K, Ctrl+D).
What I Need

Configuration for auto-formatting on save that matches VS Code/Visual Studio behavior
Information about:

Required configuration files and their locations
Necessary plugins and installation steps
LSP setup for C# (OmniSharp)
Formatting configuration



What I've Tried
I've installed Neovim via Chocolatey:
choco install neovim -y

But I'm unsure about:

Which plugin manager to use
Where to put configuration files
How to configure LSP for C#
How to set up formatting that matches Visual Studio/VS Code

Questions

What files do I need to modify to configure Neovim for C# development?
What should be the content of these configuration files?
Which plugins should I install for:

LSP support
Code formatting
C# specific features


How do I ensure formatting consistency with VS Code and Visual Studio?

System Information

OS: Windows
Neovim Version: 0.10.2 (installed via Chocolatey)
Visual Studio Professional 2019
VS Code with C# extension
Primary work: .NET Framework and WPF XAML

P.S. Posted an answer here. Now I need to find a way to make it work with .editorconfig so i can have consistency across different editors/IDEs.

You can use Neovim inside VS Code using the VS Code Neovim extension

@PanagiotisKanavos I want to try Neovim directly and not just the vim keybindings. I am thinking about a complete move so I can have a nice and clean CLI/TUI work environment.

It's not a binding, this does use Neovim: This extension uses a fully embedded Neovim instance,...

@PanagiotisKanavos unrelated: you don't happen to know an equivalent for Helix instead of nvim?

No, I'm just googling and not picking the first result without verifying and reading the docs. Knowing an extension existed in the first place helps. One of the popular bloggers wrote about his setup recently, but I can't remember who it was

Without the extension, the problem is a bit open-ended.  Back in February people at Reddit were talking about a forked roslyn.nvim and Omnisharp. MS essentially nuked Omnisharp 1-2 years ago when they said they won't use it as the VSCode C# extension any more. roslyn.nvim talks to the C# language server directly

I only need the autoformating functionality for now.

asked a follow-up question here
